# Error found while loading /etc/profile, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, .profile

[image: /etc/profile error]

Every time I boot up and Sign in to the account, before getting the desktop screen, I get this error message. I tried looking up stackoverflow & askubuntu but all were different from my error.

Here's the code of my /etc/profile

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

I also even tried to execute the file using command

```
$ . /etc/profile
```

but it was giving the same message as shown in the image.

[image: /etc/profile error2]

Comment: /etc/profile calls /etc/bash.bashrc (if it exists) and also all files in /etc/profile.d (if any). Check all for usage of `readlink` and `dirname`.  Also you can try to set debug mode before caling /etc/profile ... `set -x`  in the terminal.

Comment: @SorenA, could you please elaborate more? I am new to using Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the file and directory I mentioned.  In one of them there must be a reference to readkink and dirname (the two commands that gives the errors). Maybe you remember editing one of them ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `grep -E 'dirname|readlink' /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile.d/*.sh`, the error is coming from one of those files. If that has no results, that means the error is coming from a file that one of _those_ files reads, and will will need to see the content of the files.

Comment: Thanks @SorenA , I got the error solved.